# Facebook Graph API returning 400 for public user videos, but 200 for public page videos

Tags: ruby, facebook, api, http, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the graph API to get info on Facebook videos.

If I try to get video info from a public video on a Facebook page like so:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{video_id_from_facebook_page}?fields={fields}&access_token={api_key}|{api_secret}`

...it works fine. 200 and returns everything I ask for.

If I try to do the same thing with a public video from a Facebook *profile* page, like so:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{video_id_from_user_profile}?fields={fields}&access_token={api_key}|{api_secret}`

I get a 400 bad request.

Any ideas? Do I just need to use a *proper* access token when getting resources from a FB user profile, versus a page where I can just use `{api_key}|{api_secret}`? I'd really rather not have to get a proper access token since that would complicate automated testing (they expire; API keys and API secrets don't).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Turns out, according to the Graph API documentation, I actually *do* need a "user access token" to retrieve user videos.

See the "Permissions" section of: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/

(Personally, I find this a bit ridiculous if the videos are public, but it is what it is)

Comment: of course you do. just because stuff is public does not mean an app can grab it. you always need a user token for user data.